# PS CC — How to do an addition in the width/height field?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've got an old issue with Photoshop CC. I would like do to an addition in the Width / Height field of an element, just like that :

[image: Photoshop toolbar]

Does someone know how can I do ? I searched on the web, but I didn't found anything. It could save me a lot of time... !

Thanks you, cheers.

Comment: Sadly, there is no such functionality in Photoshop.  Complain to Adobe perhaps.

Comment: You can do it in Illustrator. That's probably where your confusion is coming form

Comment: As you say, it's sad... ! It's a tinny feature, but really helpfull.

Comment: You could increment the field value via arrow-up and arrow-down keys (1px or 10px with additional shift key).

Comment: I don't believe Photoshop supports operations in fields.